# Lasso not converging & ElasticNet uses all coefficients

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest, lasso-regression

Basically, I am trying to see whether doing Penalized Regression on a Random Forest can help in getting better predictions than the Random Forest itself.

What I did:

- I cleaned the dataset, removed outliers, and so on..
- Did a Train set - Split Test (0.75 (19693 obs)  - 0.25 (6565 obs))
- Performed a Random Forest on the training dataset then predictions on the test set resulting in a  `(6565,)` array with all the predictions.
- Grid Search the best Random Forest resulting in a optimal number of trees ( `n_estimators`) of `1200`.
- Running the optimum Random Forest and finding each prediction for each tree using the following code `predictions_all = np.array([tree.predict(test_features) for tree in rf.estimators_])` resulting in a `(6565,1200)` matrix (i.e if you do the mean of each row you get the prediction of the Random Forest).
- concatenate this matrix with my target variable resulting in a `(6565,1201)` matrix.
- Setting a Train set - Split Test (0.75 (4923 obs)  - 0.25 (1642 obs)).
- Doing a Ridge / Lasso / adaptiveLasso / ElasticNet on the training set and if this latter only consider some coefficients (i.e trees), compare the aggregated mean with the Random Forest we did at step 3 to see if Lasso on a Random Forest performs better than the Random Forest itself.

The problem is that when I try Ridge, Lasso & Adaptive Lasso, it doesn't converge if `alpha != 0` (OLS)

```py
from sklearn.linear_model import Lasso
lasso00001 = Lasso(alpha=0.0001, max_iter=10000,normalize=True)
lasso00001.fit(train_features,train_labels)
train_score00001=lasso00001.score(train_features,train_labels)
test_score00001=lasso00001.score(test_features,test_labels)
coeff_used00001 = np.sum(lasso00001.coef_!=0)

print("training score for alpha=0.0001:", train_score00001 )
print("test score for alpha =0.0001: ", test_score00001)
print("number of features used: for alpha =0.0001:", coeff_used00001)
```

Resulting in

```py
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/coordinate_descent.py:475: ConvergenceWarning: Objective did not converge. You might want to increase the number of iterations. Duality gap: 104843192290351.6, tolerance: 137819106237.78107
  positive)
```

I tried with `max_iter=100000` and `max_iter=1000000` but it doesn't converge as well.

**Does anybody know why ?**

However, ElasticNet converge, I tried GridSearchCV and found out the optimal ElasticNet

```py
from sklearn.linear_model import ElasticNet


EN = ElasticNet(alpha=0.02, max_iter=1000000, normalize=True, l1_ratio = 0.8)
EN.fit(train_features,train_labels)
train_EN=EN.score(train_features,train_labels)
test_EN=EN.score(test_features,test_labels)
coeff_used = np.sum(EN.coef_!=0)

print("training score:", train_EN)
print("test score: ", test_EN)
print("number of features used:", coeff_used)
print("coefs:", EN.coef_)
```

Resulting in :

```py
training score: 0.6679234101432687
test score:  0.6414639586584302
number of features used: 1200
coefs: [0.00070865 0.00107221 0.00048273 ... 0.00062971 0.00057734 0.00033563]
```

Which mean that he used every 1200 trees (variables). 
What is weird is that I need to have `alpha = 6500` so that he only uses 1199 trees (variables).

**Am I missing something?** Is that because all my variables (trees) are sensibly the same that he uses every single variable (tree) ?

Answer (score 0):

***What you missed***
Yes, that's quite normal. In fact, you're doing a penalized regression on very (very very) correlated variables. Basically, each tree learns in the same way, but that's just the dataset on which they train that differs a little bit (that's called bagging). But as they differ only a little, that will result in highly correlated variables.

***A little bit of philosophy***
I don't see why you would want to do that. Penalized regression is used when you want to keep only a few variables that are sufficient to predict (i.e. there is a lot of variables that are useless). If you had a lot of trees that were useless, better to keep less before.

Finally, in Random Forest, the number of trees are not the better thing to grid search, because more trees generally tends to give better performance. What you want is to have less so as to have less time-consuming algorithms... That's more interesting to grid search the depth of your model.

Bagging : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_aggregating, https://becominghuman.ai/ensemble-learning-bagging-and-boosting-d20f38be9b1e